# Social Engine custom page ability to add widgets and changed layout

Tags: php, socialengine

I want to create a new page like you would see in the admin layout editor. I can create a new page from there but its url is always mysite.com/pages/mypage . If i go into engine4_core_pages i can add a page that references my controller and the action i want. So lets say

```
mymodule_index_mynewpage Somepage
```

It will display in the LayoutEditor under Editing dropdown as 'Somepage'. When i select that page to either add widgets to it or change the columns all i get in the middle content area is a top Global Header and Global Footer option to hide or show. There is no open area in the middle when i can place widgets. Screen cap of what im talking about

https://i.stack.imgur.com/5JSgr.png

How can i give the page the ability to change layout and add widgets to it? I cant seem to find it.

**Edit: adding to answer below** 
After following the below directions the ability to change the layout is limited. To be able to use all of the "column layouts" you must also place into engine4_core_content.

(auto number), yourpage_id, type=container, name=middle, (parent containers incremented id), order(6 i guess), ["[]"]=params, null=attribs

```
1234 50 container middle 1000 6 ["[]"] null
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At first, you have to create new row in engine4_core_content with type 'container' and name 'main' (of course page_id there is your page_id). Main container contains 'left', 'right' and 'middle' containers.

Then, in the end of action that refers to your page (mymodule_index_mynewpage), you can use something like this to display content which configured using layout editor for your specific action:

```
$this->_helper->content
        ->setContentName(48) // page_id
        ->setNoRender()
        ->setEnabled();
return;
```

Answer (score 0):

There are two tables in socialengine which store information about pages and widgets that are used by layout editor:

- engine4_core_pages
- engine4_core_content

Both are related by the field "page_id".

You have to take in mind this structure:

```
page (defined in engine4_core_pages)
    |
    ----- container (defined in engine4_core_content, field: type)
                 |
                 ----- widgets (defined in engine4_core_content, field: type)
```

Check info in both tables and in your project check the file install.php (inside of //settings